# iOS 9 is 'Picture In Picture' mode available with 'Requires Fullscreen' set to YES?

Tags: cocoa-touch, avfoundation, ios9

I have an app that requires fullscreen, but want to make Picture In Picture feature available when user opens video playback modal controller (My own player written with AVFoundation).
I have 'app requires fullscreen' flag set to YES in settings.

Can I use Picture in Picture mode for video playback while all my app requires to be fullscreen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created a sample project and found that YES, Picture In Picture feature doesn't depend whether your app needs fullscreen or not.

Maybe this would be helpful for those who are looking for the same question as I did.

1. Set base SDK version to latest (9.0)
2. Set "App requires fullscreen" flag in the project settings
3. Set `AVAudioSession` category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

   ```
   [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
   ```
4. Just created AVPlayerViewController and presented it from my root controller

   ```
   AVPlayerViewController *moviePlayerController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
   AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:12345/movie.mp4"]];
   moviePlayerController.player = player;
   [self presentViewController:moviePlayerController animated:YES completion:nil];
   ```
5. PiP button appeared at the bottom right corner of playback controls and it works!

P.S. I may remove the question and answer if it's obvious or too simple and nobody find it useful.